# How to get match result by given range using regular expression?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm stucking with my code to get all return match by given range. My data sample is:

```
        comment
0       [intj74, you're, whipping, people, is, a, grea...
1       [home, near, kcil2, meniaga, who, intj47, a, l...
2       [thematic, budget, kasi, smooth, sweep]
3       [budget, 2, intj69, most, people, think, of, e...
```

I want to get the result as: (where the given range is intj1 to intj75)

```
         comment
0        [intj74]   
1        [intj47]    
2        [nan]   
3        [intj69]
```

My code is:

```
df.comment = df.comment.apply(lambda x: [t for t in x if t=='intj74'])
df.ix[df.comment.apply(len) == 0, 'comment'] = [[np.nan]]
```

I'm not sure how to use regular expression to find the range for t=='range'. Or any other idea to do this?

Thanks in advance,

Pandas Python Newbie

Comment: `intj\d+` matches `intj` followed by one or more digit.

Comment: @Maroun Maroun thanks for replying. Unfortunately it's not working. Return all [nan].... Or how exactly to apply your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace `[t for t in x if t=='intj74']` with, e.g.,

```
[t for t in x if re.match('intj[0-9]+$', t)]
```

or even

```
[t for t in x if re.match('intj[0-9]+$', t)] or [np.nan]
```

which would also handle the case if there are no matches (so that one wouldn't need to check for that explicitly using `df.ix[df.comment.apply(len) == 0, 'comment'] = [[np.nan]]`) The "trick" here is that an empty list evaluates to `False` so that the `or` in that case returns its right operand.

Comment: Yess!!! After import re, solution re.match('intj[0-9]+$', t) works well. Thank you so much @ewcz

Comment: And again thanks @ewcz for the "trick" shared. I've tried and it worked, and even shorten my code.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to `pandas` as well. You might have initialized your DataFrame differently. Anyway, this is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'comment': [
        "intj74, you're, whipping, people, is, a",
        "home, near, kcil2, meniaga, who, intj47, a",
        "thematic, budget, kasi, smooth, sweep",
        "budget, 2, intj69, most, people, think, of"
    ]
}
print(df.comment.str.extract(r'(intj\d+)'))
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting .str.extract, it's another way to do it. However i get FutureWarning: currently extract(expand=None) means expand=False (return Index/Series/DataFrame) but in a future version of pandas this will be changed to expand=True (return DataFrame)
  if __name__ == '__main__':. All my result were NaN.

Comment: You can be explicit and pass the expand argument: `df.comment.str.extract(r'(intj\d+)', expand=True)`. True will return a DataFrame. False will return a Series. Use what suits you.

Comment: Oh i see. Thanks for explanation @arvindpdmn